# How to use sed to replace some content of a give string (not file)

Tags: replace, sed

This is what I want:

```
echo "abc" | sed 's/a/b/g'
```

But if I write it like this:

```
sed 's/a/b/g' "abc"
```

It will remind me:

```
sed: abc: No such file or directory
```

What's the correct command to let `sed` treat `abc` as a string not a file?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `echo "abc" | sed ...`. Indeed, it's quite common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
echo "abc" | sed 's/a/b/g'
```

or  "here strings":

```
sed 's/a/b/g' <<< "abc"
```

more example & details: http://linux.die.net/abs-guide/x15683.html and

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Here_strings

Answer (score 1):

The command is already right, but you've some misconceptions about pipelines. Let's see an example:

I have a file with *abc* as a content, so the command:

```
cat test | sed 's/a/b/g'
```

produces:

```
bbc
```

Nothing wrong here. Now, check man:

```
sed [-Ealn] command [file ...]
```

So, when you use pipelines you're working with stdin (standard input) and stdout (standard output).

*sed* command accepts both files as argument, or standard input.
The example you've written is wrong because "abc" **is not a file**.

More info:

- Pipelines: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29
- man sed